# 'jpg_name' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]

Tags: c, pointers, char

```
int counter = 0;
char *jpg_name;
sprintf(jpg_name, "%3i.jpg", counter);
FILE *photo = fopen( jpg_name, "w");
counter++;
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
'jpg_name' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]
```

I'm trying to write file names using the `sprintf` function. I think I must somehow be declaring the `char*` in an incorrect way, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's complaining because you're using an uninitialized pointer, not because of the content. Try to `malloc` some memory.

```
char *jpg_name = malloc(ENOUGH);
```

Alternatively you can just use a `char` array.

---

Side note: you might consider `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`.

Comment: Okay.  It's an array, if I need three chars, I should malloc enough memory for three bytes, as well as enough bytes for the chars "jpg_name"?  (The first slot in any array is taken up by the name of the array, right?)

Comment: @newbie_hannah Just count the number of symbols :-)

Comment: you need to allocate enough for all the chars you'll be adding, and 1 additional slot for a null-terminator character. No slot is used for the name of the array, the variable name just points to the memory that you've allocated.

Comment: So in this case 4 bytes should do it.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: @newbie_hannah No, you probably need more.

Comment: @newbie_hannah count again: with a single-digit counter, you'll need 5. `.jpg` is 4, 1 more for the digit, and one more for the null-terminator. And if your counter can grow to 2, 3, ... digits, you'll need more characters.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to allocate memory for the string that you're building.

```
char jpg_name[MAX_LEN + 1];
snprintf(s, MAX_LEN, "%3i.jpg", counter);
```

You can also use `malloc`:

```
jpg_name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (MAX_LEN + 1));
```

In your case, `MAX_LEN` should be at least 5, assuming that you'll only have single-digit counters. If your counters can grow to multiple digits, you'll need to account for that with a larger `MAX_LEN`.

As for your error: the compiler will warn you when you're using variables that haven't been initialized: set to some value. You aren't initializing your `char*` so the compiler complains, but this can also happen e.g. with an uninitialized `int`. Get in the habit of initializing your variables to a default value.