# May be used uninitialized in this function for struct assignment and then segmentation during runtime

Tags: segmentation-fault

I am experiencing issue with assigning values to my struct elements. 
I get a warning message above during the compile
when i try to assign values to it, i get the warning message above.
  How do i get rid of it.. Is it just a matter of initializing?? And how do I initialize the struct before using it .

I tried to run it with the warning message and i get a segmetation fault error

Newbie in c.. please bear with me

```
struct outrec {
    char *cny_cd;
    char *region_cd;
    char *region_name;
    char *city_name;
    char *postal_code;
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
    int metro_code;
    int area_code;
    char *out_time_zone;
    char *cityrangeip_start;
    char *cityrangeip_end;
    char *orgname;
    int  orgnetmask;
    char *orgrangeip_start;
    char *orgrangeip_end;
    char *isporgname;
    char *domainname;
    int  domainnetmask;
    char *domainrangeip_start;
    char *domainrangeip_end;
};

in the main program i called an instance of it
```

struct outrec result_outrec;

```
      printf("Storing values in struct \n" ); 
        strcpy(result_outrec.cny_cd, _mk_NA(gir->country_code));
        strcpy(result_outrec.region_cd, _mk_NA(gir->region));
        strcpy(result_outrec.region_name,_mk_NA(GeoIP_region_name_by_code(gir->country_code, gir->region)));
        strcpy(result_outrec.city_name,_mk_NA(gir->city));
        strcpy(result_outrec.postal_code,_mk_NA(gir->postal_code));
        result_outrec.latitude=gir->latitude;
        result_outrec.longitude=gir->longitude;
        result_outrec.metro_code=gir->metro_code;
        result_outrec.area_code=gir->area_code;
        strcpy(result_outrec.out_time_zone,_mk_NA(time_zone));
        strcpy(result_outrec.cityrangeip_start,(ret[0]));
        strcpy(result_outrec.cityrangeip_end,(ret[1]));
```

Newbie in c.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd have entered your warning message in Google you would have found
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958931/c-warning-x-may-be-used-uninitialized-in-this-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618671/jpg-name-may-be-used-uninitialized-in-this-function-werror-uninitialized) question which are basically the same and have a perfectly decent answer.
Basically, you are declaring pointers but don't make them point to an actual piece of memory (initialize them), which causes the warning. After that you copy data into the not existing memory they point to, which causes the segfault.